# Dimension of singlet subspace of $2N$ identical spin-1/2 particles

Tags: quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

Consider a quantum system of $2N$ identical spin 1/2 particles, each having a 2D Hilbert space $V$. The total Hilbert space is the tensor product $V^{\otimes 2N} \equiv V \otimes \cdots \otimes V$. Define the total spin operator as

$$
\mathbf{S} = \sum_{i=1}^{2N} \mathbf{S}_i
$$

Let $V_0$ be the subspace of $V^{\otimes 2N}$ which has zero total spin:

$$
V_0 = \{|\psi\rangle \in V^{\otimes 2N} | \ \mathbf{S}^2 |\psi\rangle = 0\}
$$

What is the dimension of $V_0$? In [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0605103), it is stated that (below Eq. 23)

$$
\dim V_0 = \frac{1}{N+1} \binom{2N}{N}
= \frac{(2N)!}{N!(N+1)!}
$$

The combination number $\binom{2N}{N}$ can be naively understood as requiring the total $S^z = 0$ (number of different ways to choose $N$ spins with spin-up; the other $N$ spins have spin down). But I am having trouble in understanding the additional $1/(N+1)$ factor. Can someone please explain it? In addition, from the point of view of reducing the tensor product of $N$ copies of the fundamental (spin-1/2) representation of SU(2), what are the basis vectors in $V^{\otimes 2N}$ that furnish these $(\dim V_0)$ copies of the trivial (spin-0) representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can already see you miscounted for *N* = 1, just two particles. There is  only *one* singlet in their tensor product, not two! You need the denominator of 2 to cut down on the superfluous/fake multiplicity you inferred. For *N* =2, 4 particles, you need to divide by 3 to get the answer, one singlet as a composition of two intermediate singlets, and one singlet as a composition of two intermediate triplets.

Your reference's well-known formula is just equation (12) in [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physleta.2016.12.006) reference, for *s* =0 and *n* = 2*N*, following from (7), or, easier, the [Catalan triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle#General_formula) structure in the bottom formula of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Tensor_product_space) in Wikipedia, an ancient result: [Zachos, 1992](https://doi.org/10.1142%2FS0217732392001270).

The Catalan coefficient for  the correct multiplicity, in agreement with your reference, is
$$
C(2N,N)= \binom{2N}{N}-\binom{2N}{N-1}, 
$$
as explained; or you might just evaluate the easy integral (7), a direct approach.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Wikipedia says $C(x,y)$ is the number of strings consisting of $x$ X's and $y$ Y's such that no initial segment of the string has more Y's than X's. But how is the case $x = 2N$ and $y = N$ related to the singlet state?

Comment: Think of the [random walk](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nuclphysb.2016.09.023) utilized...